# How to find suitable Product Package for below structure?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, opencart, prestashop

How to **find suitable product package** for below structure with **PHP** or **MySQL**?

I have 2 tables that store *product package* details:

**`products_packages`**

```
products_package_id | package_title | package_description | package_offer_type | package_offer_value
```

**`products_packages_items`**

```
auto_id | products_package_id | products_id | package_offer_value | qty_min | qty_max
```

1. **products_packages:** is used to store package details

   - `package_offer_type` is *%*
   - `package_offer_value` is *10*
2. **products_packages_items:** is used to store related products for products_packages

**How to decrease *10%* amount for each product package item?**
**How to find best suitable product package that gives customer more discount?**

I have *cart details* array that contains order product details. How to find suitable package for product?

```
[cart_details] => Array
    (
       [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1
                [quantity] => 100
                [price] => 10.00

                [product_title] => Standard Business Cards                    

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 81
                [quantity] => 100
                [price] => 10.00

                [product_title] => Metallic Business Cards                    

            )
    )
```

Comment: What is this question about? I do not get it? Do you want us to recommend an e-commerce solution? Who is considered to be *credible and/or official source* here at **stackoverflow**?

Comment: This question could be closed for several reasons: *off topic*, *unclear what are you asking* and because of too many different questions in this one also as *too broad*. The bounty you have offered is useless unless you rapidly improve your question (to remove all that close-vote reasons).

Comment: You need to improve this question. Say how you populate array from DB and where do expect to appy discont: in DB or in app.

Comment: What cart system are you using?  You've listed 3 and in one of your comments you've mentioned simple cart.  You're not going to get an answer unless you've decided on your store platform.

Comment: is it really a Magento linked question ?

Answer (score 1):

My undeerstanding of your question is:

> You are providing discounts in Packages. A Package has discounts on several Products.
>   When a customer buys a group of Products (Cart) you need to find which discount Package will bring most value to the customer.

In order to do that, you need to calculate savings for each Discount Package applied to the Cart. Then pick Package with maximum monetary savings. If several Packages tie - pick any of them.

*UPDATE 1.* since there is no Cart table, we'll get "cart" by selecting Product IDs from main Products table

```
select top 1 Package_id from (
    select 
        Packages.Package_id,
        Prod_id, 
        Quantity * Price * Packages.Discount as ProductDiscount
    from Products
    join PackgeItems on Products.Prod_id = PackageItems.Prod_id
    join Packages on Packageitems.Package_id = Packages.Package_id
    where Products.Prod_ID in ( <comma separated list of Prod_IDs from Array> )
)
group by Package_id
order by sum (ProductDiscount) Desc
```

You can add one or 2 selects in the middle for testing purposes.

Comment: yes right but in my case Cart is not a table it simple cart array

Comment: I bielive you get cart data from the database for prod IDs? How do you communicate with DB?